# Examples for a K-module with K ring, but not an integral domain?

Tags: modules

I am looking for an example for such a module, because I want to find a module for which the set of torsion elements is not a submodule of $M$.

Comment: Would $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$ suffice?

Comment: As a module over itself?

Comment: You ask two seemingly unrelated questions.  Lord Shark the Unknown provided an answer to the thread's header.  On the other hand, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1939173/torsion-elements-do-not-form-a-submodule answers the thread's main question.

Comment: thanks for boths answers!